# What approach to using Google AdSense with a website that expects a lot of visits but only during a short period?

Tags: google-adsense

I am building a website that if the marketing is successful will receive a lot of visits but only over a short period, of perhaps 2-10 days. Let's say it gets between 500,000 and 50,000,000 visits.

So the site is at the opposite end of the spectrum from those which generate ad income from a constant flow of lower-level traffic over a period of months or years.

What is the best approach to use towards Google AdSense in these circumstances?

Comment: Generally, Google only approves Adsense accounts for websites have lots of unique good content, thin sites and particular niches will be rejected. I assume this site has lots of content?

Comment: It won't have much content but it will be unique. It's a one-week wonder thing that will get a lot of interest from being featured in major media for its big idea, but only for a few days.